# Unable to retrieve query param from the Path: "xxx/:id?version=:version" in Vertx

Tags: kotlin, get, vert.x, query-string

I am unable to retrieve query param from the Path: 
`/xxx/:id?version=:version`in Vertx.

When I try to visit: `localhost:8080/xxx/1?version=a`

I would expect `routingContext.request().getParam("id")` to return `1` and `routingContext.queryParams()` to return MultiMap containing `verison : a`
But it is not hitting the desired method.

I tried putting breakpoint and observed that it is not hitting the desired method in the backend(`xxx/:id?version=:version`). Instead it is hitting the method with the Path `xxx/:id`

Question: Am I passing/handling query params incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the route you only have to define the **path parameters**, you do it correctly:

```
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/xxx/:id");
```

The query parameters you don't have to define, you can just access to them by:

```
routingContext.request().queryParams();
```

If you are looking for something specific, like in your case the version, you can access it by:

```
String version = routingContext.request().getParam("version");
```